What are easic?
I just stumbled on this

eASIC AdvantageOptimize your custom eASIC solution for power, performance and fast time-to-deployment. Obtain ASIC level performance whether your application is logic, DSP or IO dominated. Achieve up to 80% lower power consumption than equivalent FPGA implementations

But it looks like unlike cpld, eAsic didn t took over fpga. So what s the downside of eAsic compared to fpga? Why a design should be tested on fpga first before using an eAsic?

I'm  not going to click the link ... it looks like spam

please put all info into your post, so that a link is not required

I clicked on it. The link is broken "Temporarily Offline".

@Rodo works again.

eASIC Corporation is a fabless semiconductor company that was acquired by Intel. The term eASIC is now used as a trademark for some ICs by Intel. In more general terms these devices are called structured ASICs.
They are somewhere in the middle between FPGAs and standard-cell ASICs in the sense that there is some customization of silicon masks. So they are not necessarily field-programmable and they don't require a full custom set of masks as in a regular ASIC. This means that you cannot just reprogram it to fix functional problems as in an FPGA. Functionality is set at time of production.
Here is some more to read: anandtech.com article

See also Intel's product page. They are not at all field-programmable, but the customization is limited to a single mask step in the production process. They are to traditional FPGAs what the mask ROM is to SRAM or EEPROM.

Advantages:

"Instant On" - no time lost to loading a configuration file.
Nonvolatile configuration - more resistant to external disturbances.

Disadvantages:

6-week turnaround time for design changes.

Your question speaks in the past tense, and your link is to an archived web page, but eASICs are current products from Intel. They aren't intended to replace traditional FPGAs, but there are niche applications in which their advantages would be significant.

They are currently sold but Intel designed no new products and thus nothing like 10nm based die.
